# Display in block only if there is no data

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

In Drupal 7, you can add headers and footers to blocks that will display even when the view generating them has no results.

Is there any way to use PHP to display text in one of those areas when the view returns no results? The same thing expressed in pseudocode:

```
if view has no results:
  echo "Custom message/code here"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View has such "No results behavior" built-in.

You can find than under "advanced" section.

Comment: Thanks! Another option hiding in plain sight.